# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, select, join, sqldatasource

I started getting this error in ASP.NET Gridview SQLDataSource. Everything was fine. In the Edit Column, Gridview I accediently added the same colum (ID) twice but then I removed it. I started getting this error. I am not passing anything anywhere. It is a simple select statement which joins the two tables.

```
SELECT T1.[ID], T1.[amg_id], T1.[FirstName], T1.[LastName],  
T2.[UserName] FROM [T1] JOIN T2
on T1.ApplicationUserID = T2.UserID
```

I could not figure how where I am getting this error. Then I copied my SQL statement from SQLDatasource to SQL Server Management Studio. Surprisingly I got the same error. If I split the join and pull the records individually, both queries work fine. Don't know where is the problem and how it got started. The same query ran fine before.I hope to reply to this question, once I find the solution. SQL Error is here:

```
Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

Comment: Please post your SQL query here

Comment: query posted - nothing strange with it

Comment: more hint. Query result flashes for a second in SQL Management Studio and then throws this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only one idea about this issue - the types of T1.ApplicationUserID and T2.UserID are different ...  I think that this flash appears because of error you've mentioned.  Please check the data types, what are they?

Comment: correct, one has uniquIdentifier, other nvarchar(255), used to work without any problem though or may be I changed something

Comment: This worked for me as well. Same as @Thecrocodilehunter this was working before.